# Видеопоздравления сообщества сообществу!

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено

Много лет назад, когда я учился в колледже, мы с несколькими однокурсниками очень любили по–доброму подшучивать друг над другом, в том числе при необходимости поздравить с чем–либо. Я крайне рад, что на Stack Overflow есть похожая замечательная [традиция <strike>веселиться</strike> надевать шляпы под Новый год](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CDi_nj1-G6U). С другой стороны, во многих коллективах принято, чтобы кто–то один, избранный (избранный народом), например, руководитель, поздравлял коллектив с праздником. Исходя из моего опыта, намного веселее, когда все поздравляют друг друга, особенно лично! Еще веселей — когда поздравляют нетипично!

**Спешу предложить нам видеопоздравить друг друга с наступающим Новым годом в шляпах!**

Несколько ключевых моментов задумки:

- Поздравление должно быть в видеоформате.
- Длина видео должна быть до минуты.
- Необходимо, чтобы на человеке в кадре было надето что–либо на голову (шапка, шляпа, маска), настоящее или виртуальное.
- Было бы совсем замечательно, если бы в вашем видеопоздравлении вы упомянули несколько участников, чей вклад в развитие сообщества вам запомнился более всего в этом году! (Если, попытавшись несколько раз, вы не успеваете перечислить всех за 10 секунд, пожалуйста, просто используйте «всех». Хотя, выделив несколько участников, вы, несомненно, сделаете им приятно!)

[image: видеочат]

<sub>Кадр из выпуска №2 видеочата сообщества, где я «использую» свою любимую шляпу.</sub>

Пожалуйста, присылайте снятое вами видео мне на почту nicolas.chabanovsky@stackoverflow.com до 23:58 четверга 28–го декабря 2017 года. Я постараюсь собрать из видео один ролик и выложить его вечером в пятницу на [Мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Пожалуйста, не стесняйтесь записывать ваше поздравление на любое устройство: видеокамеру, камеру ноутбука, смартфон! Снимайте в удобном для вас месте: за рабочим столом, на кухне офиса, в транспорте во время дороги на работу — в любом месте! Главное — не качество видео или пейзаж, а ваши пожелания коллегам (и, конечно же, оригинальный головной убор)!

Уверен, ваши теплые слова несомненно согреют коллег на всю оставшуюся зиму, какой бы холодной она не была! С нетерпением ждем ваших поздравлений!

---

Автор самого веселого поздравления получит самый интересный секретный сувенир! :)

**Обновлено**

Готово: http://youtube.com/watch?v=tTnxDOw2oDw&feature=youtu.be

Comment: сдается мне не взлетит

Comment: Как? И это тоже? Ну хорошо, — пацаны и девчонки, сворачиваемся! @Grundy говорит, не взлетит! (Или кто–то просто хочет приз взять?)

Comment: недоверие чувствуется в словах твоих @Nicolas

Comment: @Grundy не рубите инициативу на корню, а то скоро и таких инициатив не будет

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, а почему продолжительность ролика только 2-10 сек. Количество поздравлений будет ведь не несколько сотен. А намного меньше. Зачем зажимать участников в такие, жёсткие рамки. Вот первое поздравление появилось от Arhada, строчит как пулемет из-за ограничений по времени. Я не с первого раза понял, кого он поздравляет, о чём говорит. :)

Comment: @Alexandr_T Идея была в том, что если поздравлений будет много, то мы все равно уложимся в какую–то адекватную общую длительность. Вероятно, вы правы. Спасибо! Убрал ограничение.

Comment: Да, я старался говорить супер-коротко, но и то заняло 12 секунд... а за 2 секунды, можно только улыбнуться ))

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин http://vgif.ru/gifs/138/vgif-ru-15701.gif

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Подскажите, пожалуйста, порадуете ли вы сообщество поздравлением? Я лично с нетерпением его жду!

Comment: Уж вечер близится!

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин В процессе. Пока не могу победить несколько «дефектов». Если совсем ничего не выйдет, выложу как есть!

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин Готово! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tTnxDOw2oDw&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Позитивные ребята! Интересно получилось. Всем спасибо, с Наступающим и вас всех!

Comment: Урааа! Всех ребят и девчат с наступающим новым годом!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, ответы - в ответы?

Comment: @Qwertiy Почему бы и нет!

Comment: Когда искал видеопоздравление у него было 256 просмотров ))