# Итоги 2017 года

Tags: поддержка, итоги-года

Подводя итоги уходящего года, хотелось бы отметить несколько наиболее запомнившихся событий:

- Выборы. Выборы. Выборы!

  - [Сообщество сделало прекрасный выбор новых модераторов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6225/). Ими стали [@ЮрийСПб](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/17609/) и  [@Qwertiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178988/). Уху!
  - [Большинством голосов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5496/) было решено выбирать владельцев главного чата сообщества голосованием. Первыми выбранными владельцами стали: [@alexolut](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/176217/), [@Abyx](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/177684/).
  - [Стартовали выборы представителей сообщества Stack Overflow на сайте ВКонтакте](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6590/). Кто станет избранниками сообщества, узнаем совсем скоро!
- [Мы вместе запустили видеочат сообщества!](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCwwnMkw2Lok36TtjEVd7uqQ) Видеочат — уникальная возможность нетематического общения в реальном времени, где мы знакомимся с выдающимися участниками [сообществ Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites).
- [Стартовало исследование о создании связей между вопросами на разных языках](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4857/) — невероятно полезная функция, которая призвана улучшить связи между базами знаний системы сайтов Stack Overflow, а как результат — увеличить доступность знаний.
- Наш сайт [получил](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5312/) новый дизайн шапки сайта и вкладку «[интересные вопросы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6542/)» как домашнюю страницу.
- В этом году мы достигли показателей в [100 000+ участников в сообществе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6582/) и [233 вопроса в день](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0zbv.png)!

Уходящий год в цифрах:

```
 -------------------------------------------------------------
|                    | Stack Overflow     |  Stack Overflow   |
|                    | на русском         |  на русском       |
|                    | 2016 год           |  2017 год         |
|--------------------|--------------------|-------------------|
|  Задано вопросов   |     52 714         |    65 363         |
|--------------------|--------------------|-------------------|
|Опубликовано ответов|     56 221         |    62 819         |
|--------------------|--------------------|-------------------|
|  Новых участников  |     28 980         |    44 182         |
|--------------------|--------------------|-------------------|
|     Уникальных     |     5 345 000      |    6 534 000      |
|     посетителей    |                    |                   |
|--------------------|--------------------|-------------------|
|   Просмотренных    |     26 150 000     |    35 418 000     |
|      страниц       |                    |                   |
 -------------------------------------------------------------
```

Сообщество растет, как и создаваемая нами база знаний — судя по всему, в 2017 году сайт стал одним из самых крупных русскоязычных сообществ, посвященных разработке программного обеспечения. Уверен, в 2018 году мы подтвердим это почетное звание, а наш вклад в развитие индустрии ИТ будет сложно не заметить! Огромное спасибо всем, кто активно участвует в жизни русскоязычного сообщества разработчиков!

#### В будущем году нам есть над чем трудиться!

Основные векторы развития, которые, на мой взгляд, являются критическими для сообщества:

- Очень хочется (и уверен, многие разделяют это желание), чтобы в будущем году в нашем сообществе по–прежнему нашлось место каждому, кто стремится стать или является разработчиком, вне зависимости от пола, возраста, достатка, «официального» образования или чего–либо еще. Единственно важный для нас критерий — истинное, неудержимое желание разобраться, как «оно работает». Мы — люди очень разные: собрать всех на одном сайте, в одном сообществе невозможно без взаимного уважения и дружелюбия. По моему мнению, [помимо великолепных правильных ответов!] отказ от агрессии, эмпатия к ближнему и добродетель знатоков является важнейшей причиной, почему наши коллеги каждый день выбирают Stack Overflow (то есть нас с вами!) как сообщество, где им точно помогут, даже в самой сложной ситуации.
- Больше людей — больше идей! Было бы очень здорово в новом году увидеть всех, кто был частью Stack Overflow в течение прошлых лет, и много новых коллег, которые обязательно привнесут в сообщество «частичку себя»: кто–то поделится знаниями про интерфейс пользователя, кто–то с энтузиазмом расскажет про драйверы, а кто–то добавит в сообщество новые процессы! Реальные люди — самая важная часть Stack Overflow.
- Уникальность Stack Overflow в том, что содержимое сайта — это знания множества людей в кристаллизованном виде: минимум необходимого по каждому прикладному вопросу. Десятки тысяч авторов, как будто бы сговорившись, решили написать одну коллективную работу! Без каждого из нас коллективной прикладной энциклопедии не существовало бы, вклад каждого — неоценим! Каждый новый ответ по–своему неповторим и уникален, в нем содержится жизненный опыт автора, и чем больше различных, пусть немного похожих, но все же разных, ответов дано в каждом вопросе, тем глубже понимание вопроса у всего сообщества. Ведь каждый вопрос и ответ имеют невероятный коэффициент масштабирования: отвечая один раз в одном ответе, вы помогаете сотням, а [в ряде случаев](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/greatest-hits) и сотням тысяч коллег! (Хочу заметить, что единицы книг в мире печатаются/покупаются такими тиражами!) Больше ответов — глубже знания сообщества!

#### Поздравляю всех участников и пользователей Stack Overflow на русском с наступающим Новым годом и желаю всего наилучшего! Буду рад видеть вас в новом году! Нас всех ждет много интересного!

Нажмите на картинку ниже, чтобы посмотреть [видео–поздравление сообщества сообществом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6636/)!

[image]

Пожалуйста, обратите внимание:

- У вас есть мысли, идеи и видение развития сообщества? [Пожалуйста, оставьте ваш отзыв о Stack Overflow!](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6653/) Ваш лучший подарок для нас — ваше честное мнение о работе сайта и мысли по улучшениям!
- Чтобы не скучать на новогодних каникулах, предлагаю вам принять участие в [традиционных Зимних играх](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6654/)!

Comment: а кто входит в _- 2m52s SPb Python User Group_? :-)

Comment: @Grundy Приходите на встречу сообщества петербургских Python–разработчиков и узнаете!